# Spring Data Elasticsearch custom @Query with more than 10 parameters

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 2.1.0.RC1.

I have a custom query (via @Query annotation) where I want to pass 11 parameters. The query looks like this:

```
{
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [
          {
            "range" : {
              "attribute0" : { "gte" : ?0, "lte" : ?1 }
            }
          },
          {
            "range" : {
              "attribute1" : { "gte" : ?2, "lte" : ?3 }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": { "attribute2": "?4" }
          },
          {
            "term": { "attribute3": "?5" }
          },
          {
            "term": { "attribute4": "?6" }
          },
          {
            "term": { "attribute5": "?7" }
          },
          {
            "term": { "attribute6": "?8" }
          },
          {
            "term": { "attribute7": "?9" }
          },
          {
            "term": { "attribute8": "?10" }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

In my repository, it looks like this:

```
@Query("{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"attribute0\":{\"gte\":?0,\"lte\":?1}}},{\"range\":{\"attribute1\":{\"gte\":?2,\"lte\":?3}}},{\"term\":{\"attribute2\":\"?4\"}},{\"term\":{\"attribute3\":\"?5\"}},{\"term\":{\"attribute4\":\"?6\"}},{\"term\":{\"attribute5\":\"?7\"}},{\"term\":{\"attribute6\":\"?8\"}},{\"term\":{\"attribute7\":\"?9\"}},{\"term\":{\"attribute8\":\"?10\"}}]}}")
Page<Entity> findAllByAttributes(
          Integer param0, Integer param1, 
          Integer param2, Integer param3, 
          String param4, String param5,
          String param6, String param7,
          String param8, String param9,
          String param10, Pageable pageable);
```

The problem is, I can't use more than 10 parameters (single digit index ?0 to ?9). The **placeholder ?10 gets resolved to placeholder 1 with a zero appended**.

I can't find anything in the Spring Data Elasticsearch reference documentation on any limitations in the number of parameters.

How can I pass more than 10 parameters into the @Query?

Comment: Hmm weird, since the pattern used to figure out the parameters is `"\?(\d+)"` (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/query/ElasticsearchStringQuery.java#L38))

Comment: I added the repository method definition. Maybe it has something to do with the escaping/preprocessing of the query?

Answer (score 5):

Spring Data is the very big project in way of playing with data world

As I know, We can have one more way to do the same thing in different way.

Spring data has one more annotation which would help to treat the method parameter as query parameter.

> **Annotation: @Param**

This annotation can be used with the method parameter itself. Please find below format which can help to extend the method parameter count to use with spring data.

**Explaination**: You can include N no. of method parameter with **`@Param`** annotation. Please find below valid expression to write annotation.

```
@Param("param0")
```

Now, when you add this @Param annotation with method parameter, you must need to specify parameter in **`@Query`** with the prefix of  `colon (:)`. Something like **param0** in below query,

> @Query("{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match": {"userId":
>   "**:param0**" }}]}}}")

**Complete Example:** You can see org_id is the query parameter.

```
@Query("{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match": {"userId": ":org_Id"}}]}}}")
List<User> getByOrgId(@Param("org_Id") String orgId)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue as well.  I'll file a bug.

poor mans fix try using numbering like ?00, ?01, ?02

Digging in the code the issue is not in the regular expression but the replace command seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/query/ElasticsearchStringQuery.java#L38)

```
result.replace(group, getParameterWithIndex(accessor, index));
```

which of course will replace all and thinks `?1` needs to be replaced in both `?1` and `?10`

Comment: please check my comments on your PR